# Regex - Negotiate capture group

Tags: regex

I'm not a regex expert.
I have the following regex, which seems to work fine, to get a number with 2 decimal values using as decimal splitter `.` or `,`.

```
/([0-9]*[\.|\,]{0,1}[0-9]{0,2})/g
```

This should be the behaviour:

```
1 => should be valid
1.1 => should be valid (same with using `,` instead of `.`)
1.23 => should be valid (same with using `,` instead of `.`)
1.235 => should be invalid
-1 => should be invalid 
abc => should be invalid 
1a => should be invalid ...
```

A regex to test, you can find here:

https://regex101.com/r/qwdN7o/1

But my issue is now, to negotiate the whole regex expression. I want to get all which is not matching the regex. I already tried this:

```
^(?!([0-9]*[\.|\,]{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}))
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Maybe just `^\d+(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/8wTxZU/1))? Or are you using the regex for live input validation?

Comment: Yes, it will be used for live input validation. It seems that your regex is returning the valid results, but not the invalid ones, too

Comment: may be you can use this `(?<!\S)(?!\d+(?:[.,]\d{0,2})?)\S+` you can check: https://regex101.com/r/qwdN7o/2

Comment: Then you need `^[0-9]*(?:[.,][0-9]{0,2})?$`, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get all which is not matching the regex.

If you want to match all the words that don't match number pattern then use:

```bash
(?<!\S)(?!\d+(?:[.,]\d{0,2})?)\S+
```

**Breakup:**

- `(?<!\S)`: Lookbehind to assert that previous char is not a non-whitespace
- `(?!\d+(?:[.,]\d{0,2})?)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have a numbered text ahead of us
- `\S+`: Match 1+ non-whitespace
  [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/qwdN7o/2)

Or if you want to match full line that don't contain this number text then use:

```bash
^(?!.*\b\d+(?:[.,]\d{0,2})?).+
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/qwdN7o/3)